# QuickBlox: EXC_BAD_ACCESS for QBChat methods on iOS 8

Tags: quickblox

Sometimes the request made by QBChat (retrieve dialog list, chat message history, send message...) cause the app to crash.

When I traced back, the EXC_BAD_ACCESS occur in [EndpointsAPIStorage retrieveEndPoint] called in [QBQuery performInBgAsyncWithDelegate].

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: I too receive the same error.

Comment: At first I thought it was iOS 8 SDK compatible issue, but when running sample chat app and creating another project, the problem doesn't appear to happen. Kinda weird.

Comment: I tried creating another application and I still get the same error.

Comment: After digging around, I found out that the problem might related to Crashlytics, in which when I remove Crashlytics, the problem magically went away. For testing purpose, I suggest you to follow the sample-chat app, with the basic flow like this: 1) Open app --> run splashscreenVC that create QBsession. 2) Once done, go into the app, and the first thing to call is to get all dialogs from QB (which is the most common crash that I got before).

Comment: Interesting. It seems my crash comes from a completely different call. Mine crashes every time on the method QBRequest createGeoData.

Comment: I have the same issue. I can create a session, but I get the crash in retrieveEndPoint when calling logInWithSocialProvider. Removing the call to [Crashlytics startWithAPIKey] fixes the issue. Is there any way to report a bug to QuickBlox?

Comment: Try to use 2.0.9 update http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Download_iOS_SDK

Comment: I'm getting the same error as well. Is your bad access code = EXC_I386_GPFLT?